# Python - condition beased on query result

Tags: python, oracle, if-statement

I have a code which saves query results to csv file. Is it possible to make condition based on query results? For example:

**if query results contains string "Test" then execute another query and save it to existing file.**

Should I use "fetchone" method?

My code:

```
try:
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('TAGATE','TAGATE','GPSPL')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print "connected"

    try:

        query = """select example1 , example 2 from dbo1""".format(line_name)
        tmp = cursor.execute(query)
        columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        results = tmp.fetchall()

        cursor.close()

    except:
        pass


except:
    print IOError

filename='{0}.csv'.format(line_name)
if results:
    csv_file = open(filename,'wb')
    myFile = csv.writer(csv_file)
    myFile.writerow(columns)
    myFile.writerows(results)
#i think another statment should be here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```
...
if results:
    for ex1, ex2 in results:
        # I assumed string was to be found in field 'Example1'
        if 'Test' in ex1:
            # Save your results as you do with csv_file = open(filename,'wb') and so on
```